# Bootstrap table with large and resizable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and want to have a table with [resizable](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-resizable) and [large](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/large-columns.html) columns.

When I have more columns, horizontal scrollbar is initiated. When I want to make columns resizable, horizontal scrollbar is destroyed because of css rule `.JColResizer{ table-layout: fixed;}` in [colResizable](https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable) plugin.

Resizable extension depends on [colResizable](https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable) plugin and on line 56

`t.addClass(SIGNATURE).attr(ID, id).before('<div class="JCLRgrips"/>');`

in [plugin's source](https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable/blob/master/source/colResizable-1.5.source.js) is added to table (`t` variable) JColResizer class (`SIGNATURE` variable). If I remove this rule, the horizontal scrollbar is shown again, but columns are not resizable.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88useqm1/5/)

**html**

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true" data-show-filter="true" data-filter-control="true" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-field="CustomerName">CustomerN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectName">ProjectN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectType">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectDetails">ProjectD</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectLocation">ProjectL</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectTiming">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectTeam">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectStatus">ProjectS</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectProgress">ProjectP</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>GE Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
         <td>Norwalk, CT</td>
         <td>Feb-Aug 2015</td>
         <td>John, Adam, Pete</td>
         <td>Running</td>
         <td>Empty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>GE Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
         <td>Norwalk, CT</td>
         <td>Feb-Aug 2015</td>
         <td>John, Adam, Pete</td>
         <td>Running</td>
         <td>Empty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>GE Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
         <td>Norwalk, CT</td>
         <td>Feb-Aug 2015</td>
         <td>John, Adam, Pete</td>
         <td>Running</td>
         <td>Empty</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#mainTable').bootstrapTable({
    resizable: true
});
```

If you add this css rule

```
.JColResizer{
    table-layout: inherit;
}
```

horizontal scrollbar is initiated, but columns aren't resizable.

**edit//**

I deleted `.JColResizer{table-layout:fixed;}` and add `$(tb).css('table-layout','auto');` in the begging and `$(tb).css('table-layout','fixed');` at the end of `var init = function( tb, options)` function in colResizable plugin. Now it works somehow...

The problem is that now columns can't be smaller - resized than their default rendered size (minWidth parameter doesn't work).